# IE doesn't work

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, ie

My JQ and CAML code are working on chrome. IE is not. I'm using SharePoint 2010 and my documentation mode is 8(default).

When I changed 8(default) to 10 or edge, it works fine, but the problem is when I refresh the site , it will automatically change to 8(default).

Comment: Did you check your browser console and see what is the error? And post your sample code.

Comment: "The value of the property '$' is null or undefined, not a Function object" If I changed to 10, it works fine.

Comment: This means your jQuery file is not loading. Which version of library is this?

Comment: I am using jq 3.2.0 min and also I tried jq 1.4.4.min

Comment: Did you execute your methods under document ready function?

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        // check if enter button is pressed and then search button clicked         event is called
            $('#txtSearch').keypress(function(e){
          if(e.keyCode==13)
         { $('#btnSearch').click();return false;}
        });
        });

Comment: It seems an issue with IE version. Check my answer below.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60331/discussion-between-sai-and-venkat-konjeti).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my suggestion:

1. Check your code, like `$(document).ready(function()` and others
2. Don't use latest version of jQuery 3.2.0 min for SharePoint 2010. Instead use this version: jQuery 1.4.4.min.js.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the IE compatible version from a master page.

```
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"/>
   .....
   .....
</head>
```

Refer to [IE compatibility support for SharePoint 2010 site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/7cef975b-a409-48cd-8da9-c5660fa55f11/override-master-page-meta-tags-from-child-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious).

P.S. Try with IE=9 or IE-10

Comment: In the head tag you can add as a first line of statement